# Insert missing rows for all the tables from one database into another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 2 databases with same set of tables. Total number of rows in each of the tables differ between the two databases. I have to insert the missing rows for all the tables from one database into another.

Is there a way I could do it all at one shot?

I can do it manually for each table with the below query:

Considering id as the unique column:

```
insert into databasename.dbo.tablename
    select * 
    from datababasename2.dbo.tablename2
    where id not in (select id from databasename.dbo.tablename)
```

I want to do this for all the tables in the database. Looking for ways to do it dynamically.

Comment: this is not magic. you can't do it in one shot.

Comment: There are a few different patterns for this. How many rows are we talking here? Are the DB's on the same server? Do you have to use SSIS? Can you have downtime for the table? Is there a unique key on the table? Answering to these questions means you will learn something new and we can pose a more ideal solution.

Comment: Do I need to do it for each table individually? Or if a dynamic sql could generate the insert statements?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there will be at the max 1000s of rows. Yes the DBs are on the same server. Yes the tables can have a downtime and each table has a unique key. I don't have to use SSIS necessarily- just looking for ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer 1000's of rows simply delete and reload. This is much simpler than trying to implement differential. Here's some code, most of which is error handling. This does not allow for a table with an identity. Let me know if this is the case.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable;

INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable (column1,column2,column3)
SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable;

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY


BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

(commit/catch pattern lifted from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150034/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041906-1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a stored procedure that contains SQL Dynamic queries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SyncDatabases
(
 @p_strSourceDatabase Varchar(50),
 @p_strDestinationDatabase Varchar(50),
 @p_Identity Bit --If your tables contains Identity columns
) AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @strQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #TblTemp(TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(50), TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR(50), [COLUMNS] VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @strQuery = 'INSERT INTO #TblTemp (TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS)
                 SELECT DISTINCT T1.TABLE_SCHEMA,T1.TABLE_NAME, (SELECT ''['' + COLUMN_NAME + ''],'' FROM  [' + @p_strSourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = T1.TABLE_NAME AND TABLE_SCHEMA = T1.TABLE_SCHEMA FOR XML PATH('''')) AS [COLUMNS]
                    FROM [' + @p_strSourceDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS T1 
                    INNER JOIN [' + @p_strDestinationDatabase + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS T2 
                    ON T1.TABLE_SCHEMA = T2.TABLE_SCHEMA
                    AND T1.TABLE_NAME  = T2.TABLE_NAME
                    AND T1.COLUMN_NAME = T2.COLUMN_NAME'


EXEC(@strQuery)

SET @strQuery = ''

SELECT @strQuery = @strQuery + CASE WHEN @p_Identity = 1 THEN 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT [' + @p_strDestinationDatabase + '].[' + T1.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + T1.TABLE_NAME + '] ON ' ELSE '' END + ' INSERT INTO [' + @p_strDestinationDatabase + '].[' + T1.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + T1.TABLE_NAME + '] (' + LEFT(T1.COLUMNS,LEN(T1.COLUMNS) - 1) + ')
        SELECT ' + LEFT(T1.COLUMNS,LEN(T1.COLUMNS) - 1) + ' FROM [' + @p_strSourceDatabase + '].[' + T1.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + T1.TABLE_NAME + '] AS T1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [' + @p_strDestinationDatabase + '].[' + T1.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + T1.TABLE_NAME + '] AS  T2 WHERE T1.ID =  T2.ID);
        '
        FROM #TblTemp AS T1

EXEC(@strQuery)  


DROP TABLE #TblTemp


END
```